# Can't import a plugin for videojs

Tags: javascript, next.js, jsx, es6-modules, video.js

Here is My code

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";
import "videojs-contrib-quality-levels"; // videoJs Quality levels **
import "videojs-hls-quality-selector"; // videojs Quality Selector **

const Player = (props) => {
  const { source, options, onReady } = props;
  const [videoSource, setVideoSource] = useState(source);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const playerRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!playerRef.current) {
      const videoElement = videoRef.current;
      if (!videoElement) return;
      const player = (playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
        onReady && onReady(player);
      }));

      console.log(player);
      player.qualityLevels();  // I get error in this line that qualityLevels is not a function.
    }
  }, [options]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setVideoSource(source);
  }, [source]);
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (playerRef.current) {
        playerRef.current.dispose();
        playerRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>The implementation below is using react functions</h1>
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <video ref={videoRef} className="video-js" playsInline />
        <source src={videoSource} type="application/x-mpegURL" />
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-quality-levels/2.1.0/videojs-contrib-quality-levels.min.js"></script>
    </>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

The error I get is that `qualityLevels` is not a function for this statement: `player.qualityLevels();`

The following snippet is from the file `videojs-contrib-quality-levels`:

```
declare module 'video.js' {
    interface VideoJsPlayer {
        qualityLevels: {
            VERSION: string;
            (): QualityLevelList;
        };
    }
}
```

I should mention that I am not getting any error for my imports or anything. The only error I get is that qualitylevels is not a function.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vinama",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "cypress": "cypress open",
    "cypress:headless": "cypress run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.19.5",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "hls.js": "^1.1.1",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.3.10",
    "next": "12.0.4",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-query": "^3.34.16",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "swiper": "^8.0.0",
    "swr": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@types/node": "16.11.7",
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/react": "17.0.35",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.7",
    "@types/slick-carousel": "^1.6.37",
    "@types/video.js": "^7.3.33",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "cypress": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint": "7",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.4",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.43.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "typescript": "4.4.4",
    "video.js": "7.15.4",
    "videojs-contrib-ads": "6.9.0",
    "videojs-contrib-quality-levels": "^2.1.0",
    "videojs-hls-quality-selector": "^1.1.4",
    "videojs-playlist": "4.3.1",
    "videojs-thumbnail-sprite": "0.1.1"
  }
}
```

How can I find where the issue is?